# How to update a string by adding a character around a key value pair

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm looking for an update statement to add curly brackets around each key value in the row.
For example I would like to change this,
[8254589:false,1956027:false,46523678:false]
to this,
[{8254589:false},{1956027:false},{46523678:false}]

Comment: Does this work in that type of sql?
https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_replace.asp#:~:text=The%20REPLACE()%20function%20replaces,performs%20a%20case%2Dsensitive%20replacement.  That would allow you to change one string to another .. but as far as the logic to determine that?  Sounds like a RegEx job .... look into "Regular Expression" if you need to build logic to determine things about strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```sql
UPDATE table_name
SET   value = REGEXP_REPLACE(value, '(\d+:(true|false))', '{\1}')
WHERE REGEXP_LIKE( value, '[(,?\d+:(true|false))*]' );
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (value VARCHAR2(100));

INSERT INTO table_name (value) VALUES ('[8254589:false,1956027:false,46523678:false]');
```

Changes the table to:

> | VALUE |
> | --- |
> | [{8254589:false},{1956027:false},{46523678:false}] |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=f31be59c29dc42557ca03ea89e556770)*